# Can't get logged into Gnome

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I'm running 17.04 and have been using the gnome desktop in preparation for Ubuntu dropping Unity support.  It has been running ok..., but now when I try to login it just goes to a black screen and then comes back to the login screen.

I removed the .XAuthority file and it allowed me to login again, however, it is doing it again and now even doing that isn't helping.  I never thought I would say it but I actually miss Unity after all the problems I'm having with Gnome.

Is there any way to get this going again?  All of the problems have me wanting to go try out Suse and really not wanting to there. :-)

Thanks,

Glenn